# Why is C++ much faster than python with boost?

Tags: python, c++, performance, boost

My goal is to write a small library for spectral finite elements in Python and to that purpose I tried extending python with a C++ library using Boost, with the hope that it would make my code faster.

```
class Quad {
    public:
        Quad(int, int);
        double integrate(boost::function<double(std::vector<double> const&)> const&);
        double integrate_wrapper(boost::python::object const&);
        std::vector< std::vector<double> > nodes;
        std::vector<double> weights;
};

...

namespace std {
    typedef std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<double> > > cube;
    typedef std::vector< std::vector<double> > mat;
    typedef std::vector<double> vec;
}

...

double Quad::integrate(boost::function<double(vec const&)> const& func) {

    double result = 0.;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); ++i) {
        result += func(nodes[i]) * weights[i];
    }
    return result;
}

// ---- PYTHON WRAPPER ----
double Quad::integrate_wrapper(boost::python::object const& func) {
    std::function<double(vec const&)> lambda;
    switch (this->nodes[0].size()) {
        case 1: lambda = [&func](vec const& v) -> double { return boost::python::extract<double>(func (v[0])); }; break;
        case 2: lambda = [&func](vec const& v) -> double { return boost::python::extract<double>(func(v[0], v[1])); }; break;
        case 3: lambda = [&func](vec const& v) -> double { return boost::python::extract<double>(func(v[0], v[1], v[2])); }; break;
        default: cout << "Dimension must be 1, 2, or 3" << endl; exit(0);
    }
    return integrate(lambda);
}

// ---- EXPOSE TO PYTHON ----
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hermite)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<std::vec>("double_vector")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vec>())
        ;

    class_<std::mat>("double_mat")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::mat>())
        ;

    class_<Quad>("Quad", init<int,int>())
        .def("integrate", &Quad::integrate_wrapper)
        .def_readonly("nodes", &Quad::nodes)
        .def_readonly("weights", &Quad::weights)
        ;
}
```

I compared the performance of three different methods to calculate the integral of two functions. The two functions are:

- The function `f1(x,y,z) = x*x`
- A function that is more difficult to evaluate: `f2(x,y,z) = np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z)`

The methods used are:

1. Call the library from a C++ program:

   ```
   double func(vector<double> v) {
       return F1_OR_F2;
   }

   int main() {
       hermite::Quad quadrature(100, 3);
       double result = quadrature.integrate(func);
       cout << "Result = " << result << endl;
   }
   ```
2. Call the library from a Python script:

   ```
   import hermite
   def function(x, y, z): return F1_OR_F2
   my_quad = hermite.Quad(100, 3)
   result = my_quad.integrate(function)
   ```
3. Use a `for` loop in Python:

   ```
   import hermite
   def function(x, y, z): return F1_OR_F2
   my_quad = hermite.Quad(100, 3)
   weights = my_quad.weights
   nodes = my_quad.nodes
   result = 0.
   for i in range(len(weights)):
       result += weights[i] * function(nodes[i][0], nodes[i][1], nodes[i][2])
   ```

Here are the execution times of each of the method (The time was measured using the `time` command for method 1, and the python module `time` for methods 2 and 3, and the C++ code was compiled using Cmake and `set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)`)

- For `f1`:

  - Method 1: `0.07s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.083 total`
  - Method 2: 0.19s
  - Method 3: 3.06s
- For `f2`:

  - Method 1: `0.28s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.289 total`
  - Method 2: 12.47s
  - Method 3: 16.31s

Based on these results, my questions are the following:

- Why is the first method so much faster than the second?
- Could the python wrapper be improved to reach comparable performance between methods 1 and 2?
- Why is method 2 more sensitive than method 3 to the difficulty of the function to integrate?

---

**EDIT**: I also tried to define a function that accepts a string as argument, writes it to a file, and proceeds to compile the file and dynamically load the resulting `.so` file:

```
double Quad::integrate_from_string(string const& function_body) {

    // Write function to file
    ofstream helper_file;
    helper_file.open("/tmp/helper_function.cpp");
    helper_file << "#include <vector>\n#include <cmath>\n";
    helper_file << "extern \"C\" double toIntegrate(std::vector<double> v) {\n";
    helper_file << "    return " << function_body << ";\n}";
    helper_file.close();

    // Compile file
    system("c++ /tmp/helper_function.cpp -o /tmp/helper_function.so -shared -fPIC");

    // Load function dynamically
    typedef double (*vec_func)(vec);
    void *function_so = dlopen("/tmp/helper_function.so", RTLD_NOW);
    vec_func func = (vec_func) dlsym(function_so, "toIntegrate");
    double result = integrate(func);
    dlclose(function_so);
    return result;
}
```

It's quite dirty and probably not very portable, so I'd be happy to find a better solution, but it works well and plays nicely with the `ccode` function of `sympy`.

---

**SECOND EDIT** I have rewritten the function in pure Python Using *Numpy*.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.hermite_e as herm
import time
def integrate(function, degrees):
    dim = len(degrees)
    nodes_multidim = []
    weights_multidim = []
    for i in range(dim):
        nodes_1d, weights_1d = herm.hermegauss(degrees[i])
        nodes_multidim.append(nodes_1d)
        weights_multidim.append(weights_1d)
    grid_nodes = np.meshgrid(*nodes_multidim)
    grid_weights = np.meshgrid(*weights_multidim)
    nodes_flattened = []
    weights_flattened = []
    for i in range(dim):
        nodes_flattened.append(grid_nodes[i].flatten())
        weights_flattened.append(grid_weights[i].flatten())
    nodes = np.vstack(nodes_flattened)
    weights = np.prod(np.vstack(weights_flattened), axis=0)
    return np.dot(function(nodes), weights)

def function(v): return F1_OR_F2
result = integrate(function, [100,100,100])
print("-> Result = " + str(result) + ", Time = " + str(end-start))
```

Somewhat surprisingly (at least to me), there is no significant difference in performance between this method and the pure C++ implementation. In particular, it takes 0.059s for `f1` and 0.36s for `f2`.

Comment: C++ is a compiled language. Python is an interpreted language.

Comment: Is this a typo or can `f2` be actually simplified to `f2(x,y,z) = 5 * ( np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z))`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks. I know C++ is compiled, which is why I wanted to use it to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: What compiler and compilation flags are you using?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You're right, I just copy-pasted 5 times the same thing to illustrate my point.

Comment: You computation in `Quad::integrate` is too simple, and `func` is called very frequently. Most of the time for the Python version is spent on switching from Python interpreter to C++ code.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  I didn't specify any flags (I used CMake for the compilation and didn't set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE). I tried changing the build type to 'release', and the times are shorter, but the ratios are similar.

Comment: I have reran the code with `set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)` and have updated the times.

Comment: Re-run it with `return integrate(lambda)`.

Comment: Done. As you can see, it doesn't significantly change the run time...

Comment: Just for fun, you could rewrite it in C. I guess it would be 2-5 times faster than in C++ (with the same optimalization-level).

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond This is a bogus claim. C is a subset of C++.

Comment: People normally use `numpy` for fast linear algebra, it uses SIMD for many common operations. You should probably consider using `numpy` first before rolling out a C++ implementation.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I was a bit reluctant to moving entirely to numpy considering the time I already spent on my C++ code (I guess that's the sunk cost fallacy), but I think that you are right, and using numpy woud make good sense.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin You were right, the python + numpy method is as fast as pure C++, with the added advantage that it's much more compact!

Comment: @Rastapopoulos It may be even faster because `numpy` has vectorized implementation. In C++ you would have to use Intel MKL on Eigen to vectorize.

Comment: It's the first time I hear about these terms (MKL and SIMD), so I'll read up on that. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An alternative way**

In a bit less general way your problem can be solved a lot easier. You could write the integration and the function in pure python code and compile it using numba.

**First approach (running 0.025s (I7-4771) per integration after the first run)**

The funktion is compiled at the first call, this takes about 0.5s

function_2:

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def function_to_integrate(x,y,z):
return np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z)
```

Integration

```
@nb.jit(fastmath=True)
def integrate3(num_int_Points):
  nodes_1d, weights_1d = herm.hermegauss(num_int_Points)

  result=0.

  for i in range(num_int_Points):
    for j in range(num_int_Points):
      result+=np.sum(function_to_integrate(nodes_1d[i],nodes_1d[j],nodes_1d[:])*weights_1d[i]*weights_1d[j]*weights_1d[:])

  return result
```

Testing

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.hermite_e as herm
import numba as nb
import time

t1=time.time()
nodes_1d, weights_1d = herm.hermegauss(num_int_Points)

for i in range(100):
  #result = integrate3(nodes_1d,weights_1d,100)
  result = integrate3(100) 

print(time.time()-t1)
print(result)
```

**Second approach**

The function can also run in parallell, when integrating over many elements the gauss points and weights may be calculated only once. This will result in a runtime of about **0.005s**.

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def integrate3(nodes_1d,weights_1d,num_int_Points):

  result=0.

  for i in nb.prange(num_int_Points):
    for j in range(num_int_Points):
      result+=np.sum(function_to_integrate(nodes_1d[i],nodes_1d[j],nodes_1d[:])*weights_1d[i]*weights_1d[j]*weights_1d[:])

  return result
```

**Passing a abitrary function**

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.polynomial.hermite_e as herm
import numba as nb
import time

def f(x,y,z):
  return np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z) +np.cos(2*x+2*y+2*z) + x*y + np.exp(-z*z)

def make_integrate3(f):
  f_jit=nb.njit(f,fastmath=True)
  @nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
  def integrate_3(nodes_1d,weights_1d,num_int_Points):
      result=0.
      for i in nb.prange(num_int_Points):
        for j in range(num_int_Points):
          result+=np.sum(f_jit(nodes_1d[i],nodes_1d[j],nodes_1d[:])*weights_1d[i]*weights_1d[j]*weights_1d[:])

      return result

  return integrate_3


int_fun=make_integrate3(f)
num_int_Points=100
nodes_1d, weights_1d = herm.hermegauss(num_int_Points)
#Calling it the first time (takes about 1s)
result = int_fun(nodes_1d,weights_1d,100)

t1=time.time()
for i in range(100):
  result = int_fun(nodes_1d,weights_1d,100)

print(time.time()-t1)
print(result)
```

After the first call this takes about **0.002s** using Numba 0.38 with [Intel SVML](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html)

Comment: That approach looks really good! Would it work if the function to integrate was passed as a argument to `integrate3`?

Comment: I never have done that, but maybe this would help. http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html Please note that much of the performance comes from inlining the function in the integrate function, which is done by the jit compiler.

Comment: Still, it's really super fast, basically an order of magnitude faster than my C++ code...

Comment: Actually, the question is addressed in the FAQ: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html

Comment: @Rastapopoulos I have for completeness added, the way to pass an abitrary function to the integration routine.

Comment: Thanks! To someone who doesn't have much experience with decorators, this is really helpful! :)

Comment: I wonder what results passing the compiled function to C++ would give...

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/50097776/4045774 (low-level callback function to scipy.quad) I would expect a better performance from an inlined solution (possible SIMD-vectorization, no function call overhead)

Answer (score 5):

Your functions take vectors by value, which involves copying the vector. `integrate_wrapper` does extra copies.

It also makes sense to accept `boost::function` by reference and capture `func` by reference in those lambdas.

Change these to (note the `&` and `const&` bits):

```
double integrate(boost::function<double(std::vector<double> const&)> const&);

double Quad::integrate_wrapper(boost::python::object func) {
    std::function<double(vec const&)> lambda;
    switch (this->nodes[0].size()) {
        case 1: lambda = [&func](vec const& v) -> double { return boost::python::extract<double>(func (v[0])); }; break;
        case 2: lambda = [&func](vec const& v) -> double { return boost::python::extract<double>(func(v[0], v[1])); }; break;
        case 3: lambda = [&func](vec const& v) -> double { return boost::python::extract<double>(func(v[0], v[1], v[2])); }; break;
        default: cout << "Dimension must be 1, 2, or 3" << endl; exit(0);
    }
    return integrate(lambda);
}
```

Still though, calling a Python function from C++ is more expensive than calling a C++ function.

---

People normally use `numpy` for fast linear algebra in Python, it uses SIMD for many common operations. You should probably consider using `numpy` first before rolling out a C++ implementation. In C++ you would have to use Intel MKL on Eigen to vectorize.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try this now and report back.

Comment: So I tried passing vectors by reference with `const&` but it does not change much. I'll update the question and the times...

Comment: @Rastapopoulos Added more changes to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried that too, but it hardly changed anything (haven't updated the times this time, because they are almost exactly the same). But you're right, calling a python function repeatedly from C++ is probably the cause of the slowness.

Comment: @Rastapopoulos You did not change the lambda expression arguments. I repeat it for you: `[&func](vec const& v)`. And do not copy `boost::functions`, just do `integrate(lambda)`. That copy in your code is even worse because it ends up copying the vector because of the value vector argument. Just use `Quad::integrate_wrapper` function I changed for you.

Comment: @Rastapopoulos And change `return integrate(boost::function<double(vec)>(lambda));` to just `return integrate(lambda);`. This is where the copying of vector happens.