# Error in calculating integral for 2D interpolation. Comparing numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, numerical-integration

My optimization task deals with calculation of the following integral and finding the best values of `xl` and `xu`:

[image: mathematical formula of an integral from x_l to x_u]

Iterations take too long, so I decided to speed them up by calculating integral for all possible values `xl` and `xu` and then interpolate calculated values during optimization.

I wrote the following function:

```
def k_integrand(x, xl, xu):
    return((x**2)*mpmath.exp(x))/((xu - xl)*(mpmath.exp(x)-1)**2)
@np.vectorize   
def K(xl, xu):
    y, err = integrate.quad(k_integrand, xl, xu, args = (xl, xu))
    return y
```

and two identical arrays `grid_xl` and `grid_xu` with dinamic increment of values.

When I run the code I get this:

```
K(grid_xl, grid_xu)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-5b9df02f12b7>", line 1, in <module>
    K(grid_xl, grid_xu)

  File "C:/Users/909404/OneDrive/Работа/ZnS-FeS/Теплоемкость/Python/CD357/4 - Optimization CD357 interpolation.py", line 75, in K
    y, err = integrate.quad(k_integrand, xl, xu, args = (xl, xu))

  File "C:\Users\909404\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 323, in quad
    points)

  File "C:\Users\909404\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py", line 372, in _quad
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I guess it comes from the fact that `xl` should be always less than `xu`. 
Is there any way to compare the values of `xl` and `xu` and return NaN in case if `xl>=xu`?

In the end I want to have something like this:
[image: Table]

And to have the ability to use interpolation.

Maybe I have chosen the wrong way? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: What is `a` and `b` in your case? Providing the full error traceback would be quite helpful.

Comment: I have added the full error traceback, hope it helps.

Comment: `(b != Inf and a != -Inf)` is not possible to evaluate with `b` and `a` being arrays of multiple values. Note the source code [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.0/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py#L44-L367), on line `372` onwards; the code decides to use different integration methods depending on whether the bounds `a` and `b` is finite or not. In general, unless the `_quadpack` routines are shown to accept vector arguments, your approach won't work. The parameter description on line `75` and `77` specifically says that `a` and `b` need to be `float`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error unless I omit the `np.vectorize` decorator. Setting `xl`/`xu` values that coincide does give me a `ZeroDivisionError` though.

Anyway, there's nothing stopping you from checking the values of `xu` vs `xl` in your higher-level function. That way you can skip integration entirely for nonsensical data points and return `np.nan` early:

```
import numpy as np
import mpmath
import scipy.integrate as integrate

def k_integrand(x, xl, xu):    
    return ((x**2)*mpmath.exp(x))/((xu - xl)*(mpmath.exp(x)-1)**2)

@np.vectorize   
def K(xl, xu):
    if xu <= xl:
        # don't even try to integrate
        return np.nan
    y, err = integrate.quad(k_integrand, xl, xu, args = (xl, xu))
    return y

grid_xl = np.linspace(0.1,1,10)        # shape (10,) ~ (1,10)
grid_xu = np.linspace(0.5,4,8)[:,None] # shape (8,1)
```

With these definitions I get (following `np.set_printoptions(linewidth=200)` for easier comparison:

```
In [35]: K(grid_xl, grid_xu)
Out[35]: 
array([[0.99145351, 0.98925197, 0.98650808, 0.98322919,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan],
       [0.97006703, 0.96656815, 0.96254363, 0.95800307, 0.95295785, 0.94742104, 0.94140733, 0.93493293, 0.9280154 ,        nan],
       [0.93730403, 0.93263063, 0.92745487, 0.92178832, 0.91564423, 0.90903747, 0.90198439, 0.89450271, 0.88661141, 0.87833062],
       [0.89565597, 0.88996696, 0.88380385, 0.87717991, 0.87010995, 0.8626103 , 0.85469862, 0.84639383, 0.83771595, 0.82868601],
       [0.84794429, 0.8414176 , 0.83444842, 0.82705134, 0.81924245, 0.81103915, 0.8024601 , 0.79352503, 0.7842547 , 0.77467065],
       [0.79692339, 0.78974   , 0.78214742, 0.77416128, 0.76579857, 0.75707746, 0.74801726, 0.73863822, 0.72896144, 0.71900874],
       [0.7449893 , 0.73732055, 0.7292762 , 0.72087263, 0.71212741, 0.70305921, 0.69368768, 0.68403329, 0.67411725, 0.66396132],
       [0.69402415, 0.68602325, 0.67767956, 0.66900991, 0.66003222, 0.65076537, 0.6412291 , 0.63144388, 0.62143077, 0.61121128]])
```

You can see that the values perfectly agree with your linked image.

Now, I've got bad news and good news. The bad news is that while `np.vectorize` provides syntactical sugar around calling your scalar integration function with array inputs, it won't actually give you speed-up compared to a native for loop. The good news is that you can replace the calls to `mpmath.exp` with calls to `np.exp` and you'll end up with the same result much faster:

```
def k_integrand_np(x, xl, xu):    
    return ((x**2)*np.exp(x))/((xu - xl)*(np.exp(x)-1)**2)

@np.vectorize   
def K_np(xl, xu):
    if xu <= xl:
        # don't even try to integrate
        return np.nan
    y, err = integrate.quad(k_integrand_np, xl, xu, args = (xl, xu))
    return y
```

With these definitions

```
In [14]: res_mpmath = K(grid_xl, grid_xu)
    ...: res_np = K_np(grid_xl, grid_xu)
    ...: inds = ~np.isnan(res_mpmath)
    ...: 

In [15]: np.array_equal(res_mpmath[inds], res_np[inds])
Out[15]: True

In [16]: %timeit K(grid_xl, grid_xu)
107 ms ± 521 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [17]: %timeit K_np(grid_xl, grid_xu)
7.26 ms ± 157 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

So the two methods give the same result (exactly!), but the numpy version is almost 15 times faster.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped! I've managed to speed up my calculations by rewriting my initial integrand using np.sinh() function and added 'if' statement to K_np like you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

### Using a low-level callback function for integration

The following answer is meant as a comment to @Andras Deak answer, but is to long for a comment.

The scipy integrate functions call the k_integrand_np function multiple times, which is quite slow. The alternative of using a pure Python function is to use a [low-level callback function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html). This function can be written directly in C or in Python using a compiler like Numba. The following is a slightly modified version of this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49732825/4045774)

**Example**

```
import time
import numpy as np
import numba
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy import LowLevelCallable
from numba import cfunc
from numba.types import intc, CPointer, float64


##wrapper for a function that takes 3 input values
def jit_integrand_function(integrand_function):
    jitted_function = numba.njit(integrand_function)
    
    @cfunc(float64(intc, CPointer(float64)))
    def wrapped(n, xx):
        return jitted_function(xx[0], xx[1],xx[2])
    return LowLevelCallable(wrapped.ctypes)

#your function to integrate
def k_integrand_np(x, xl, xu):
  return ((x**2)*np.exp(x))/((xu - xl)*(np.exp(x)-1)**2)

#compile integrand
k_integrand_nb=jit_integrand_function(k_integrand_np)

#now we can use the low-level callable
@np.vectorize
def K_nb(xl, xu):
    if xu <= xl:
        # don't even try to integrate
        return np.nan
    y, err = integrate.quad(k_integrand_nb, xl, xu, args = (xl, xu))
    return y

#for comparison
@np.vectorize
def K_np(xl, xu):
    if xu <= xl:
        # don't even try to integrate
        return np.nan
    y, err = integrate.quad(k_integrand_np, xl, xu, args = (xl, xu))
    return y
```

**Performance**

```
#create some data
grid_xl = np.linspace(0.1,1,500)      
grid_xu = np.linspace(0.5,4,800)[:,None] 

t1=time.time()
res_nb = K_nb(grid_xl, grid_xu)
print(time.time()-t1)
t1=time.time()
res_np = K_np(grid_xl, grid_xu)
print(time.time()-t1)

inds = ~np.isnan(res_nb)
np.allclose(res_nb[inds], res_np[inds])

K_np: 24.58s
K_nb: 0.97s (25x speedup)
allclose: True
```

Comment: Nice job. I wonder; don't the arrays equal exactly? I suspect it's easily possible that they do, since numba-compiling should not necessarily affect the order of operations, so floating-point errors could be the same between the two methods. I also wonder if this speedup is enough to solve OP's original problem directly.

Comment: No, they are not exactly the same. I don't know really why this happens, but I suspect that Numba simplifies x**2 (or np.power(x,2)) to x*x which may not be the same in terms of precision but quite a lot faster. On SIMD-vectorized operations precision may also vary https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/performance-tips.html