# How to pass additional parameters to numba cfunc passed as LowLevelCallable to scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, scipy, numba

The documentation [discusses](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.34.0/user/cfunc.html#example) using numba's `cfunc`s as `LowLevelCallable` argument of `scipy.integrate.quad`. I need the same thing with additional parameter.

I'm basically trying to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import cfunc
import numba.types
voidp = numba.types.voidptr
def integrand(t, params):
    a = params[0] # this is additional parameter
    return np.exp(-t/a) / t**2
nb_integrand = cfunc(numba.float32(numba.float32, voidp))(integrand)
```

However, it does not work, because `params` are supposed to be `voidptr`/`void*` and they cannot be transformed to `double`. I have the following error message:

```
TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Invalid usage of getitem with parameters (void*, int64)
 * parameterized
```

I didn't find any information on how to extract values from `void*` in Numba. In C, it should be something like `a = *((double*) params)` — is it possible to do the same thing in Numba?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. Passing extra arguments through `scipy.integrate.quad`**

The [`quad` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) say:

> If the user desires improved integration performance, then `f` may be a `scipy.LowLevelCallable` with one of the signatures:
>
> `double func(double x)`
>
> `double func(double x, void *user_data)`
>
> `double func(int n, double *xx)`
>
> `double func(int n, double *xx, void *user_data)`
>
> The `user_data` is the data contained in the `scipy.LowLevelCallable`. In the call forms with `xx`, `n` is the length of the `xx` array which contains `xx[0] == x` and **the rest of the items are numbers contained in the `args` argument of `quad`**.

Therefore to pass an extra argument to `integrand` through `quad`, you are better of using the `double func(int n, double *xx)` signature.

You can write a decorator to your integrand function to transform it to a `LowLevelCallable` like so:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
import numba
from numba import cfunc
from numba.types import intc, CPointer, float64
from scipy import LowLevelCallable


def jit_integrand_function(integrand_function):
    jitted_function = numba.jit(integrand_function, nopython=True)
    
    @cfunc(float64(intc, CPointer(float64)))
    def wrapped(n, xx):
        return jitted_function(xx[0], xx[1])
    return LowLevelCallable(wrapped.ctypes)

@jit_integrand_function
def integrand(t, *args):
    a = args[0]
    return np.exp(-t/a) / t**2

def do_integrate(func, a):
    """
    Integrate the given function from 1.0 to +inf with additional argument a.
    """
    return si.quad(func, 1, np.inf, args=(a,))

print(do_integrate(integrand, 2.))
>>>(0.326643862324553, 1.936891932288535e-10)
```

Or if you don't want the decorator, create the `LowLevelCallable` manually and pass it to `quad`.

**2. Wrapping the integrand function**

I am not sure if the following would meet your requirements but you could also wrap your `integrand` function to achieve the same result:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import cfunc
import numba.types

def get_integrand(*args):
    a = args[0]
    def integrand(t):
        return np.exp(-t/a) / t**2
    return integrand

nb_integrand = cfunc(numba.float64(numba.float64))(get_integrand(2.))

import scipy.integrate as si
def do_integrate(func):
    """
    Integrate the given function from 1.0 to +inf.
    """
    return si.quad(func, 1, np.inf)

print(do_integrate(get_integrand(2)))
>>>(0.326643862324553, 1.936891932288535e-10)
print(do_integrate(nb_integrand.ctypes))
>>>(0.326643862324553, 1.936891932288535e-10)
```

**3. Casting from `voidptr` to a python type**

I don't think this is possible yet. From [this discussion](https://github.com/numba/numba/pull/1841) in 2016, it seems that `voidptr` is only here to pass a context to a C callback.

> The void * pointer case would be for APIs where foreign C code does not every try to dereference the pointer, but simply passes it back to the callback as way for the callback to retain state between calls. I don't think it is particularly important at the moment, but I wanted to raise the issue.

And trying the following:

```
numba.types.RawPointer('p').can_convert_to(
    numba.typing.context.Context(), CPointer(numba.types.Any)))
>>>None
```

doesn't seem encouraging either!

Comment: Hello, could you extent this to several arguments?

Comment: In `def wrapped (n, XX)`, n is the number of parameters and XX a list / array of parameters value. So you can easily adapt the above to any number of parameters.

Comment: You can use `double func(double x, void *user_data) ` signature to pass numpy-arrays (including some metadata like shape) and other stuff  if you are referring to this in your third point. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58561573/4045774

Answer (score 1):

Here the same technique as the first point suggested by Jacques Gaudin, but for several arguments.

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
import numba
from numba import cfunc
from numba.types import intc, CPointer, float64
from scipy import LowLevelCallable


def jit_integrand_function(integrand_function):
    jitted_function = numba.jit(integrand_function, nopython=True)
    
    @cfunc(float64(intc, CPointer(float64)))
    def wrapped(n, xx):
        values = carray(xx, n)
        return jitted_function(values)
    return LowLevelCallable(wrapped.ctypes)

@jit_integrand_function
def integrand(args):
    t = args[0]
    a = args[1]
    b = args[2]
    return b * np.exp(-t/a) / t**2

def do_integrate(func, a):
    """
    Integrate the given function from 1.0 to +inf with additional argument a.
    """
    return si.quad(func, 1, np.inf, args=(a, b,))
```