# How to use Numba to perform multiple integration in SciPy with an arbitrary number of variables and parameters?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numba

I'd like to use **Numba** to decorate the integrand of a multiple integral so that it can be called by **SciPy's Nquad** function as a **LowLevelCallable**. Ideally, the decorator should allow for an arbitrary number of variables, and an arbitrary number of additional parameters from the Nquad's *args* argument. This is built off an excellent [Q&A from earlier this year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683653/how-to-pass-additional-parameters-to-numba-cfunc-passed-as-lowlevelcallable-to-s), but extended to the case of multiple variables and parameters.

As an example, suppose the following multiple integral with N variables and K parameters:

[image: example]

The following code works, but only for two variables and two parameters (N=2,K=2). It does not work for the more general case. This is because some of the arguments in the decorator are manually enumerated (xx[0],xx[1],xx[2],xx[3] inside the *wrapped* function). The decorator would have to be edited for every different number of variables or parameters. I'd like to avoid that, if possible. Note that the *integrand* function itself takes advantage of Numpy objects and methods and so does not have this problem.

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
import numba
from numba import cfunc,carray
from numba.types import intc, CPointer, float64
from scipy import LowLevelCallable

def jit_integrand_function(integrand_function):
    jitted_function = numba.jit(integrand_function, nopython=True)

    @cfunc(float64(intc, CPointer(float64)))
    def wrapped(n, xx):
        return jitted_function(xx[0], xx[1], xx[2], xx[3])
        #xx = carray(xx,len(xx))
        #return jitted_function(xx)
    return LowLevelCallable(wrapped.ctypes)

@jit_integrand_function
def integrand(*args):
    d = np.array([args])
    return -np.exp(d.prod())

#Two variable, two parameter example
parms = np.array([2,3])
print si.nquad(integrand,[[0,1],[0,1]],parms)
```

The ideal code would use just one decorator on the *integrand* function to also run:

```python
#Three variable, three parameter example
parms2 = np.array([1,2,3])
print si.nquad(integrand,[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]],parms2)
```

The Numba [documents](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/cfunc.html#dealing-with-pointers-and-array-memory) refer to a [carray](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/utils.html#numba.carray) function that ought to return a Numpy array when given the low-level pointer and size of an array in the callback. Possibly, this could be used to generalize the code beyond the two-variable-two-parameter case. My (unsuccessful) attempt to implement this is in the two commented-out lines of code.

Help would be appreciated. Indeed, one of the Numba developers [pointed out](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/numba-users/teVqeKWnJl4) that SciPy integration was one of the reasons Numba was written, but that documentation and examples in this area are lacking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code works:

```python
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
import numba
from numba import cfunc,carray
from numba.types import intc, CPointer, float64
from scipy import LowLevelCallable

def jit_integrand_function(integrand_function):
    jitted_function = numba.jit(integrand_function, nopython=True)
    @cfunc(float64(intc, CPointer(float64)))
    def wrapped(n, xx):
        values = carray(xx,n)
        return jitted_function(values)
    return LowLevelCallable(wrapped.ctypes)

@jit_integrand_function
def integrand(args):
    return -np.exp(args.prod())

#Two variable, two parameter example
parms = np.array([2,3])
print si.nquad(integrand,[[0,1],[0,1]],parms)

#Three variable, three parameter example
parms2 = np.array([1,2,3])
print si.nquad(integrand,[[0,1],[0,1],[0,1]],parms2)
```