# Is there a way to use scipy.optimize.fsolve with jit_integrand_function and scipy.integrate.quad?

Tags: scipy, jit, numba, quad

Based on the explanation provided here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683653/how-to-pass-additional-parameters-to-numba-cfunc-passed-as-lowlevelcallable-to-s), I am trying to use the same idea to speed up the following integral:

```
import scipy.integrate as si
from scipy.optimize import root, fsolve
import numba
from numba import cfunc
from numba.types import intc, CPointer, float64
from scipy import LowLevelCallable

def integrand(t, *args):
    a = args[0]
    c = fsolve(lambda x: a * x**2 - np.exp(-x**2 / a), 1)[0]
    return c * np.exp(- (t / (a * c))**2) 

def do_integrate(func, a):
    return si.quad(func, 0, 1, args=(a,))

print(do_integrate(integrand, 2.)[0])
```

With the previous reference, I tried to use numba/jit and modify the previous block in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
from scipy.optimize import root
import numba
from numba import cfunc
from numba.types import intc, CPointer, float64
from scipy import LowLevelCallable

def jit_integrand_function(integrand_function):
    jitted_function = numba.jit(integrand_function, nopython=True)  
    @cfunc(float64(intc, CPointer(float64)))
    def wrapped(n, xx):
        return jitted_function(xx[0], xx[1])
    return LowLevelCallable(wrapped.ctypes)

@jit_integrand_function
def integrand(t, *args):
    a = args[0]
    c = fsolve(lambda x: a * x**2 - np.exp(-x**2 / a), 1)[0]
    return c * np.exp(- (t / (a * c))**2)

def do_integrate(func, a):
    return si.quad(func, 0, 1, args=(a,))

do_integrate(integrand, 2.)
```

However, this implementation gives me the error

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: convert make_function into JIT functions)
Cannot capture the non-constant value associated with variable 'a' in a function that will escape.

File "<ipython-input-16-3d98286a4be7>", line 20:
def integrand(t, *args):
    <source elided>
    a = args[0]
    c = fsolve(lambda x: a * x**2 - np.exp(-x**2 / a), 1)[0]
    ^

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function integrand at 0x11a949d08>))
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-16-3d98286a4be7> (14)

During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function integrand at 0x11a949d08>))
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-16-3d98286a4be7> (14)
```

The error is coming from the fact that I am using fsolve from scipy.optimize inside the integrand function.

I would like to know if there is a workaround this error and if it is possible to use the scipy.optimize.fsolve with numba in this context.

Comment: It is unfortunately not possible to apply Numba's njit decorator on code containing Scipy function calls.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little python wrapper for Minpack, called `NumbaMinpack`, which can be called within numba compiled functions: https://github.com/Nicholaswogan/NumbaMinpack. You can use it to `@njit` the integrand:

```py
import scipy.integrate as si
from NumbaMinpack import hybrd, minpack_sig
from numba import njit, cfunc
import numpy as np

@cfunc(minpack_sig)
def f(x, fvec, args):
    a = args[0]
    fvec[0] = a * x[0]**2.0 - np.exp(-x[0]**2.0 / a)

funcptr = f.address # pointer to function  

@njit
def integrand(t, *args):
    a = args[0]
    args_ = np.array(args)
    x_init = np.array([1.0])
    sol = hybrd(funcptr,x_init,args_)
    c = sol[0][0]
    return c * np.exp(- (t / (a * c))**2) 

def do_integrate(func, a):
    return si.quad(func, 0, 1, args=(a,))

print(do_integrate(integrand, 2.)[0])
```

On my computer, the above code takes 87 µs, while the pure python version takes 2920 µs

Comment: Very interesting. Would that also work with Numba's guvectorize decorator? And with target='cuda'? Can NumbaMinpack do more general things than root finding, e.g. Gauss fitting?