# What methods can be used to speed up this Python code involving nested for loops?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cython, numba

I have the following code which involves summing up over a number of nested for loops.

What are some ways I can speed up the execution of this code? I am interested in not just one method of speeding it up, I'd really like to see a range of methods, e.g. 'Pure Python', Numpy, Scipy, Cython, etc..

This is so that for similar, but (much) more complicated, code I have to write I could choose a speed up option that gives a good trade-off of execution speed vs. complexity of implementation. Anything to save me from having to write C++ code which will cause me to lose the will to live.

```
def f(a,b,c,d):
    return a+b+c+d

x = [0.04691008, 0.23076534, 0.5,        0.76923466, 0.95308992]
w = [0.11846344, 0.23931434, 0.28444444, 0.23931434, 0.11846344]
numQuadNodes = 5

def tensorGauss(func):
    sum = 0;
    for i in range(0,numQuadNodes):
        for j in range(0,numQuadNodes):
            for k in range(0,numQuadNodes):
                for l in range(0,numQuadNodes):
                    sum += w[i]*w[j]*w[k]*w[l]*func(x[l],x[k],x[j],x[i])

    return sum

print(tensorGauss(f))
```

**Edit - More realistic code**
As you can see tensorGauss is already much faster than nquad (0.07 secs vs 20.86 secs on my machine), but I really would like to have some ways to make tensorGauss faster again as I will have to compute a ton of tensorGauss evaluations!

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as LA
from scipy.integrate import nquad
import time

##################################################
# Triangle vertices
##################################################
v_a_1 = np.array([[4,0,0]]).T
v_a_2 = np.array([[5,1,0]]).T
v_a_3 = np.array([[4,2,0]]).T

v_b_1 = np.array([[4,0,0]]).T
v_b_2 = np.array([[5,-1,0]]).T
v_b_3 = np.array([[4,-2,0]]).T

##################################################
# g_tau
##################################################
def g_tau():
    J_tau = v_a_2-v_a_1
    J_tau = np.append(J_tau, v_a_3-v_a_2,axis=1)
    G = np.dot(J_tau.T,J_tau)
    return np.sqrt(LA.det(G))

##################################################
# g_t
##################################################
def g_t():
    J_t = v_b_2-v_b_1
    J_t = np.append(J_t, v_b_3-v_b_2,axis=1)
    G = np.dot(J_t.T,J_t)
    return np.sqrt(LA.det(G))

##################################################
# chi_tau
##################################################
def chi_tau(x):
    return v_a_1 + (v_a_2-v_a_1)*x[0] + (v_a_3-v_a_2)*x[1]

##################################################
# chi_t
##################################################
def chi_t(y):
    return v_b_1 + (v_b_2-v_b_1)*y[0] + (v_b_3-v_b_2)*y[1]

##################################################
# k_
##################################################
def k_(x,y):
    return LA.norm(x+y)

##################################################
# k
##################################################
def k(x,y):
    return k_(chi_tau(x),chi_t(y))*g_tau()*g_t()

start=time.time()

##################################################
# tensorGauss
##################################################
x = [0.04691008, 0.23076534, 0.5,        0.76923466, 0.95308992]
w = [0.11846344, 0.23931434, 0.28444444, 0.23931434, 0.11846344]
numQuadNodes = 5

def f(z, y, x, w):
    a_1_1 = z;
    a_1_2 = z * w;
    a_2_1 = z * x;
    a_2_2 = z * x * y;

    a_1 = np.array([a_1_1,a_1_2]).T
    a_2 = np.array([a_2_1,a_2_2]).T
    res = k(a_1,a_2)

    a_1_1 = z * x;
    a_1_2 = z * x * y;
    a_2_1 = z;
    a_2_2 = z * w;

    a_1 = np.array([a_1_1,a_1_2]).T
    a_2 = np.array([a_2_1,a_2_2]).T
    res += k(a_1,a_2) 

    a_1_1 = z * y;
    a_1_2 = z * w;
    a_2_1 = z * x;
    a_2_2 = z;

    a_1 = np.array([a_1_1,a_1_2]).T
    a_2 = np.array([a_2_1,a_2_2]).T
    res += k(a_1,a_2)     

    return res

def tensorGauss(func):
    sum = 0;
    for i in range(0,numQuadNodes):
        for j in range(0,numQuadNodes):
            for k in range(0,numQuadNodes):
                for l in range(0,numQuadNodes):
                    sum += w[i]*w[j]*w[k]*w[l]*func(x[l],x[k],x[j],x[i])

    return sum

start=time.time()
tensorGauss_res = tensorGauss(f)
end=time.time()
tensorGauss_time = end-start


start=time.time()
[nquad_res, err] = nquad(f, [[0,1], [0,1], [0,1], [0,1]])
end=time.time()
nquad_time = end-start

print(f'tensor-gauss: {tensorGauss_res}')
print(f'nquad:        {nquad_res}')
print('\n')
print(f'tensor-gauss time: {tensorGauss_time}')
print(f'nquad time:        {nquad_time}')
```

Comment: Is it intentional that there are a lot of duplicate cases in there? Permutations of `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` all yield the same partial result. Is `f` costly in your "real" code, or traversing the data?

Comment: I agree. if you can tell us what do you want to calculate on tensorGauss() exactly. we can help you may be.

Comment: Looks quite similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48811580/4045774 Is the Number of integration points always 5?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I defined the function f in the above code as simply as possible just for the sake of example. The real f's I have to deal with are much more awkward. I will edit in some new code to show the type of f's I am dealing with.

Comment: @max9111 The number of integration points will not always be 5, it could any where from about 2 to 50 I imagine in practise.

Comment: @YoucefBenyettou I have edited a true example of what the f function will generally look like.

Comment: It looks like all your code is eligible for Cython. You may want to give Cython's parallelism a try: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html

Comment: So in a real world example the v_a_1 and v_b_1 arrays are of shape (3,n), where n is quite big and you want to do the integration on all triangles?

Comment: @max9111 Yes, however, the integrands (not the dummy one above) are singular so they need to be regularized. When they are regularized I end up integrating on on the domain (0,1)^4 as in the above post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-wrote your tensorGauss() function as below:

```
def tensorGauss(func):

    w_gen = np.meshgrid(w,w,w,w,indexing='ij')
    x_gen = np.meshgrid(x,x,x,x,indexing='ij')
    sum = np.sum(w_gen[0] * w_gen[1] * w_gen[2] * w_gen[3] * 
                            f(x_gen[3], x_gen[2], x_gen[1], x_gen[0]))

    return sum
```

and it printed a result of `2.0`, as opposed to the value of `1.9999999999999971` printed by the simplified `tensorGauss` that you posted (the one that uses the simplified `f()` function).

However, some disclaimers:

1. Whether this would even run without throwing errors, would depend upon your real code (the stuff that's got names like `g_tau`, etc). I say this because, this solution assumes that your `f` is a vectorized function that will work element-wise if arrays are passed instead of scalars. I can see that this assumption holds for your dummy `f()`, but then, I don't know if it will also hold for your real `f()`
2. Whether you get any performance benefits or not with this solution is also best checked with your real code instead of the dummy `f`, and your real data size